# Query on Read Uncomitted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I am currently trying to create an application which is based on a movie database. I am parsing some json files and inserting them into a SQL Server database.

So, `foreach parent element` from the `json file` I am checking if it's already in my table. If it isn't I am inserting it. Also, I insert genres for this movie and I check if that genre is in my `Genres` table but I get an exception here after 10 minutes.

My code is something like this:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = 
           new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, 
                                  new TransactionOptions
                                      {
                                         IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted,
                                         Timeout = System.TimeSpan.MaxValue
                                      }))
{
    foreach(parent element)
    {
       // check 
       if !database.movies.any(s=>s.Title == myParentElementTitle)  
       {
           insert movie;
           **- check if !database.MovieGenre.Any(s=>s.Name==myParentElementGenre) -**   
           // NOTE: I get a Time out exception here
       } 
    }

    ts.Complete();
}
```

How can I complete my transaction without getting that exception? I've set read uncommitted to allow any commands to execute, but it doesn't seems right.

Comment: Have you checked the Indexes on the table?
How many Rows does the table have?

Comment: If there are no concurrent users you could read the existing titles and genres in lists first. Saves many database roundtrips.

Comment: No, I'm the only one. The project it's local.

Comment: So, what exception? How many queries run before it occurs?

Comment: I would make this two operations. Read uncommitted to find out if the movie exists, then insert it (within a transaction) then read to see if the genre exists, then insert it if needed (also within a transaction). I wouldn't be surprised if DML when suppressing a transaction isn't creating multiple transactions under the hood and causing this hang up somehow.